# How to convert a ket vector into a bra vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Suppose I have been given a ket vector $$|i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$$ and I want to find the corresponding bra vector. How can I do that?

**My attempt :**
My guess is that the corresponding bra vector would be something like :
$$\langle i| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle u| + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \langle d|$$
But I am not sure about it. Any help/hint is appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Jakob That is an answer. It's not appropriate to put answers in comments. It is possible that it will be deleted.

Comment: Hint: have you tested your guess by computing $\langle i|i\rangle$?

Comment: @J.G. ah I see, that's not correct. The correct one should be $$\langle i| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle u| - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \langle d|$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bras are the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of kets; thus, as said by @Jacobs, you have to take the Hermitian adjoint of $|i\rangle$, which means taking  the transpose of the complex conjugate. For numbers it's just equal to the complex conjugate. For example,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle\to\langle u|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
since the coefficient is real.